# Change size of FontAwesomeIcon

Tags: css, reactjs, svg, icons, font-awesome

I'm using it as inside a button but I don't know how to change its size, to make it smaller more exactly.

```
import { faSort } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

... 

<button
  className="my-button"
  onClick={() => this.doSomething()}
  type="button">
  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faSort} />
</button>
```

I've tried in Developer tools to add `width`, `height`, `size` with different values but the icon doesn't change its size. Is it because it's SVG?

Is there a way to make it smaller?

Comment: change it with `font-size`

Comment: The component also has a `size` prop with some preset values i.e. small, large, 2x, 3x, etc

Answer (score 6):

FontAwesome comes with predefined sizes which you can control trough attribute size like this:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" size="xs" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" size="lg" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" size="6x" />
```

But to gain full control I'd recommend adding a classname:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon="spinner" className="inside-button" />
```

Which can be controlled with CSS like this:

```
.inside-button {
  font-size: 16px;
  color: white;
}
```